# C++ compiling error template-related

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie in c++ and I have this piece of code:

```
#include "passenger.h"
#include "plane_list.h"

int main(){
  plane_list<T>::plane_list();
  plane_list<T>::add();
}
```

and I don't understand nor can I seem to find an answer online why I get these errors:

> error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
>   plane_list::plane_list();
>
> error: template argument 1 is invalid
>   plane_list::plane_list();
>
> error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
>   plane_list::plane_list();
>
> error: ‘::add’ has not been declared
>   plane_list::add();

This is the header file:

```
template <class T> class plane_list{
friend class planes;
public:
  plane_list();
  ~plane_list();
  int search(const std::string &flight_code);
  plane_list<T> del(const std::string &flight_code);
  plane_list<T> add();

private:
  T *element;
  int length;

};

template <class T> plane_list<T>::plane_list(){
  element = new T[100];
  length=0;
}

template <class T> int plane_list<T>::search(const std::string &flight_code){
  for(int i=0;i<length;i++)if(element[i]._flight_code==flight_code)return i;
  return 0;
}

template <class T> plane_list<T> plane_list<T>::del(const std::string &flight_code){
  if(search(flight_code)!=0){
    for(int i=search(flight_code); i<length; i++)element[i-1]=element[i];
    length--;
    return *this;
  }
  else
    std::cerr<<"Did not find flight"<<std::endl;
}

template <class T> plane_list<T> plane_list<T>::add(){
  element[length]=planes::planes();
  length++;
  return *this;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your `plane_list.h` contents? You need to specify an actual type instead of `T` (which is just used within the template definition). For example `plane_list<int>::plane_list();`

Comment: You probably should revise how templates work. Youre supposed to instantiate the template with an actual type (not the `typename T` used in the header)

Comment: You've made a list template that can only be instantiated for `plane` elements. That doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no type `T`. I am assuming that `plane_list` is some template class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class plane_list{
//...
}
```

Here the typename `T` is a placeholder for some type that will be provided when you instantiate the class.

You are getting an error because you are trying to instantiate the `plane_list` with a type that does not exists.

To use your class correctly you need to change T to some other type:

```
//for example you could use an int
int main(){
  plane_list<int>::plane_list();
  plane_list<int>::add();
}
```

Without knowing the contents of `plane_list.h` I cannot infer what you are actually trying to do.

EDIT:

As suggested in the comments. You are using the incorrect syntax for instantiating and using your variable. The correct usage would be:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  //create a variable of type plane_list<int> names "list:
  plane_list<int> list; //default constructor is called automatically

  list.add(); ///call the member function "add"
}
```

Additionally your code has a memory leak, you allocate the array 'element' with dynamic storage by calling `new` in your constructor, but never call `delete element` anywhere which causes the leak. There are several ways to fix this:

1. Add a destructor and call `delete element` in it.
2. Use `std::vector<T>` if you need to resize the array.
3. Use `std::unique_ptr<T>` if you need a fixed length array of runtime determined length.
4. Don't use dynamic memory since you are allocating an array with compile time size.

I will not provide an example of each of these, but I would recommend reading up on memory management in C++.

Go through your header and be sure to correct the your function call syntax. There are a few places where you are using the same incorrect syntax within your class. For example:

```
template <class T> plane_list<T> plane_list<T>::add(){
  //element[length]=planes::planes();
  element[length]=planes{}; //default initialize a "planes" object
  length++;
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: `plane_list<int>::plane_list();` appears to simply be calling a default constructor and it's unlikely `add` is a static method. It's likely OP meant to make an instance of `plane_list<int>`. I fell this issue also needs to be addressed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that is a possibility, but until we are provided with a copy of the header it is pointless to try and infer the intent of the OP

Comment: Sorry for not including the header file, I edited the question.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I revised some things and thanks too your tips I managed to make it run. Thanks for your time.